# 'HTML5 Up and Running' Geolocation code example not working for me

Tags: html, geolocation

I'm studying HTML5 Geolocation and have attempted to create the final example in Chapter 6 of 'HTML5 Up and Running':
https://github.com/Level-Up/Dive-into-HTML5/blob/master/geolocation.html

My code is live here: (revised link)
http://dirtysugar.com/html5/geolocation.html and it doesn't do anything.

I would very much appreciate if someone who knows their way around this subject would take a look and let me know what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Your site appears to be unavailable.

Comment: Sorry about that. That site appears to be going in and out. I posted the link elsewhere. http://dirtysugar.com/html5/geolocation.html

Answer (score 0):

I found just a couple of small problems.

To your `<body>`, add this code:

```
<div id="live-geolocation"></div>
<div id="geo-wrapper"></div>
```

Then, up in your `<head>`, it looks like you're pulling in *version 3* of the Maps API, whereas your code references version 2 ("new GMap2"). So use this line instead:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&v=2&sensor=false"></script>
```

With those changes, I was able to get this running on my localhost.